# How to avoid feeding same batch name in database

Tags: sql, database, vbscript, scada, scadalts

I Have a Entry field "Batch name" linked to sql data base . The batch name is entered manually by me for each batch through scada system . With this batch name I will sort sql database table and retrieve data pertaining to this batch name only.

Now I am looking for vbscript that will not allow any previously entered batch name to be entered again and will pop a message "Batch name already exist".

Comment: What have you tried so far? Anytime something is manually entered, there will always be a mistake. If you log which batches you have already run, then just check that table first. You are going to need example tables for any really come out of this question.

Answer (score 0):

In new ScadaLTS, we may this in several ways but we use java-script (not VBScript):

1. Create virtual data source with virtual data point Alphanumeric (Series) settable.
2. Create meta data source with the point and when value change then validate (in java-script)  unique name.

Another way:

1. Create virtual data source with virtual data point Alphanumeric (Series).
2. And save data use java-script with REST who the previous data checks whether or not the value added.

Another way:

1. Contact the Scada LTS programmers and request for the implemented data type set. (To which by default you will not be able to add duplicates).